# Dereferencing a char pointer when its equated to another char pointer

Tags: c

Here is my code

```
    char *sptr = "abc", *tptr;

    *tptr = *sptr;

    printf("ch = %c\n", *tptr);
```

Now, when we declare a pointer, no memory is allocated to store char variable. So, this code does run and `'a'` is printed on the console. I know that `"abc"` is a string literal and its a read only memory. But when I execute `*tptr = *sptr` , where is `*tptr` is stored ?

Comment: `*tptr = ....` is UB, as `tptr` is uninitialized pointer and it is being dereferenced.

Comment: You need `tptr = sptr;`

Comment: "where is *tptr is stored" It is stored at some "random" location. Wherever that uninitialized variable points to.

Comment: Your title suggests that you want to assign the first pointer to the second pointer. Your code is very different from that.

Comment: Just like you and I can see that `*sptr` is `'a'`, so can the compiler. And it can just decide to print `a` without bothering to use the pointers. "Constant propagation" happens all the time.

Comment: @BoP -- since this is UB the compiler can "decide" to do whatever it wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment `*tptr = *sptr;` invokes undefined behavior, since you're storing through an undefined pointer.  It's a severe bug.  Instead, you can do `tptr = sptr;`, which gives `tptr` the same value as `sptr`.

Comment: Even though my Cygwin gcc compiler prints the output, I see that this is an undefined behaviour as it should be. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
     +--------+      +---+---+---+----+
sptr | 0x1234 | -->  |'a'|'b'|'c'|'\0'|
     +--------+      +---+---+---+----+                            

     +--------+      
tptr | 0xABCD | -->  Unspecific address
     +--------+
```

You do

```
*tptr=*stpr;
     +--------+           This causes UB because
tptr | 0xABCD | -->  'a'  you write to an Unspecific address
     +--------+
```

This changes the `char` which `tptr` points to, but `tptr` can point anywhere and you overwrite that random `char` that is may or may not used somewhere else, causing undefined behaviour.

What you probably want to do:

```
tptr=stpr;
     +--------+      +---+---+---+----+     
tptr | 0x1234 | -->  |'a'|'b'|'c'|'\0'|
     +--------+      +---+---+---+----+   
                       ^
     +--------+        | 
tptr | 0x1234 | -------+
     +--------+
```

This sets the pointer `tptr` to the same address as `stpr` points to, i.e. the string `"abc"`.